# Binding two Observable Collections with each other

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have two properties of `ObservableCollection<string>` type (in separate projects); What I want to do is to bind these two using reflection and `SetBinding` like this -

```
//Get the PropertyDescriptor for first collection property
PropertyDescriptor relatedPropertyDesc = prop.Find(firstCollPropName, false);
Binding relatedPropBinding = new Binding(relatedPropertyDesc.Name);
relatedPropBinding.Source = this.SelectedItem;
relatedPropBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
//Bind the second collection property using binding created above
propItem.SetBinding(MyItem.SecondCollProperty, relatedPropBinding);
```

This `SecondCollProperty` is then bound to a ComboBox's `ItemsSource`.

As such this works correctly, values present in firstCollProperty are displayed correctly in combobox; but **if some changes are made in firstCollProperty at run time then they are not reflected in ComboBox!**(adding new items or creating new collection object).

Changes are reflected correctly after refreshing the binding(again executing the above code).

My question is - **If two `ObservableCollections` are binded together why any changes in first doesn't get reflected in other?** but same thing works for properties of string or double type.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Any idea? Let me know if my question is not clear or doesn't make sense?

Comment: Your question is somewhat strange because I can see no reason to bind two collections. Why not use the same collection in both places?

Comment: @robertos: Thanks for asking that, my scenario consists of a property grid(PG) and a designer(separate projects), In designer I have an object whose properties needs to be displayed in PG; One(or more) of the property of this object is of collection type, PG will fetch that through reflection and bind it to a local property of collection type(present in particular property Item). As PG just have name of this property(which can vary) it needs another local property of collection type for binding purpose.

Comment: Although I will try to fetch the property value in PG and bind that directly; thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Just going through some old unanswered questions and saw this.  Undoubtedly you've come up with a workaround by now, but my recommendation would be look into something like CLinq, Bindable Linq, or Obtics for this.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167622/bindable-linq-vs-continuous-linq) for more details.  You'd take the first collection, create a dynamic query against it, and expose that dynamic query (which implements IObservableCollection) as your second property.

Comment: There's a nice one called OLinq on Nuget/Github