# Partial Binding to a List or ObservableCollection, Based on a Property

Tags: c#, wpf, list, filtering, observablecollection

I've looked and looked, but I have yet to find someone who's faced the same problem that I'm trying to solve - and yet I think it's the type of thing a lot of people could probably benefit from:

Simply put, I'd like a List (an ObservableCollection, ideally) that I could bind to a ListBox, a DataGrid, ComboBox, what have you. But I don't just want to simply bind to the entire list - rather, I'd like to bind to a particular set within the list that match a criteria. I'd like it to be Observable so that the item manages itself and nothing is reset. Another way to put it is Filtered Binding, perhaps...

For example, imagine a list:

```
FilteredObservableCollection<Person> people = new FilteredObservableCollection<Person>();
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Smith", IsMale = True });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe", IsMale = False });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Fanny Mae", IsMale = False });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Freddie Mac", IsMale = True });
```

I'd then bind my DataGrid:

myDataGrid.ItemsSource = people;

The myDataGrid would list all people by default.

But then if I set:

```
people.Filter = "IsMale"
```

FilteredObservableCollection would only be a list of males (while still maintaining the complete, and un-filtered list)

Or maybe I'm over-thinking this - maybe it's possible with some tricky use of Converters and Triggers? I do know that there are some controls - Telerik controls, and others - which can provide some level of filtering on datagrids, but I'm looking for a solution that's more on the side of the Collection, rather than the object to which the collection binds.

Anyway, before I go deriving my own ObservableCollection, I figured I'd see what other people have experienced...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few open-source libraries of LINQ-styled extension methods that achieve this.

[This thread makes a good comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167622/bindable-linq-vs-continuous-linq) of them... We use [BindableLinq](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/) to good success though the primary developer is no longer maintaining it.

Comment: Some how The Cars' "Just What I Needed" started playing in my head.